# hreview combined with schema's review itemtype

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata, structured-data, microformats

For some years I'm using on products pages the hreview microformat for product's reviews. Accordingly, to Google's Structured data testing tool, everything is fine with the hreview but I got some warnings for the Product and among those warnings, I got one for the "review" section. I want to get rid of that warning. I'm using schema.org microdata for the product page and I tried to add the schema.org "Review" item type for the reviews, along with the hreview.

So my question is: is there a problem or a bad practice to combine hreview with [review microdata](https://schema.org/Review) from schema.org?

I created an example of my review section:

```
<div class="hreview review-wrapper" itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
    <div class="hidden item">
        <a class="url fn" href="product.com">
            <img src="/images/product.jpg" alt="umbrella" class="photo" />
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="vcard reviewer">
        <div class="author">
            Review added by: <span class="fn" itemprop="author">John Doe</span>
        </div>

        <div class="adr">
            <div class="locality"><span>from Paris</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="rating" itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
        <span itemprop="ratingValue">5</span>
    </div>

    <div class="write-date">
        Written on <abbr class="dtreviewed">15th february 2019</abbr>
        <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2019-02-15">
    </div>          

    <div class="review-content">
        <div class="description">
            <p>
                <span itemprop="description">This is the best umbrella ever</span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I;d personally avoid marking up the same information in different formats. It increases the chance that the wrong format is chosen, that has incomplete data. If you microdata is complete, I would drop the hreview.

Comment: Interesting opinion. Thank you!

Comment: "everything is fine with the hreview": when testing your snippet, I get one error for the Microdata, and two errors for the Microformat. The Microdata error is easy to fix (adding `itemReviewed`), and one of the Microformat errors, too (using correct date format). So, this leaves this error for your Microformat: "The review has no reviewed item specified." -- is this the error your question is about?